# Why do the following rules conflict in NGINX?

Tags: nginx

I have these two rules :

```
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|js|png)$ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:44843$request_uri;
    }

    location /pc {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:12345$request_uri;
    }
```

The URI :

/pc/asser/somefile.js

falls in teh second rule, why ?

is it a question of lower priority of  the "location /pc" rule ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx [documentation](http://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/configuration/basic#sph_server-configuration) defines it:

Directives are processed in the following manner:

- Exact string matches are processed first. If a match is found, nginx stops searching and fulfills the request.
- Remaining literal string directives are processed next. If the "^~" argument is used, then ngnix stops here and fulfills the request. Otherwise, nginx continues to process location directives.
- All location directives specified by regular expressions (with the ~ and ~* arguments) are processed. If a regular expression matches the request, nginx stops here and fulfills the request.
- When there are no regular expressions, or no regular expressions match, the most specific literal string match is used.

So you should use regular expression for /pc too:

```
location ~ /pc/.* {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:12345$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first nginx check locations defined using the prefix strings (prefix locations).
And only after, it checks locations defined using regular expressions, in the order of their appearance in a configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location specifies the order in which nging location directives are looked at:

```
To find a location matching a given request, nginx first checks locations defined  
using the prefix strings (prefix locations). Among them, the most specific one is 
searched.
```

Basically the problem here is that prefix locations are always given priority over regex ones

So in your config, if both blocks match, it's the /pc prefix one that gets priority